# How can I create lag variable for a particular variable for each ID

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna create a lag variable named `lag_ins`

Which look likes:

```
year  ID    emissions   ins    lag_ins

2010   1     10          0       Nan
2011   1     20          1       0
2012   1     30          1       1
2010   2     10          1       Nan
2011   2     20          0       1
2012   2     40          1       0
```

I have used following codes:

```
df['ID'] = df.groupby(['year']).cumcount()+1
df4['lag_ins'] = np.insert(df.ins.values,0,0)[:1]
df.loc[df.groupby(["ID"]).cumcount() == 0,'lag_ins']= np.nan
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you explain what the logic behind `lag_ins` is? And what is `df4` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do `groupby.shift`:

```
df['lag_ins'] = df.groupby('ID').ins.shift()

df
#   year  ID  emissions  ins  lag_ins
#0  2010   1         10    0      NaN
#1  2011   1         20    1      0.0
#2  2012   1         30    1      1.0
#3  2010   2         10    1      NaN
#4  2011   2         20    0      1.0
#5  2012   2         40    1      0.0
```

And if you need the shift operation to be ordered by `year`:

```
df['lag_ins'] = df.sort_values('year').groupby('ID').ins.shift()

df
#   year  ID  emissions  ins  lag_ins
#0  2010   1         10    0      NaN
#1  2011   1         20    1      0.0
#2  2012   1         30    1      1.0
#3  2010   2         10    1      NaN
#4  2011   2         20    0      1.0
#5  2012   2         40    1      0.0
```